# parcoord, only one line accross all groups

Tags: r

I have this data frame, where both vectors have the same elements but in different orders:

```
df <- data.frame(G1=c("b","a","e","d","c"), G2=c("c","d","e","b","a"))
```

And then I compare them, using G1 as reference. So all terms are re-ordered accordingly in G2

```
df$G1.num <- 1:length(df$G1)
df$G2.num <-  match(df$G2,df$G1)
```

When I plot this with `parcoord`, I see how the positions of the elements in G1 change when in G2

```
  df <- subset(df,select = c(G1.num, G2.num))
    parcoord(df, col = rainbow(nrow(df)))
```

Since I have a very large data set, with many elements, the plot looks very confusing. Therefore. I would like to do one plot per elements. **For example:** element "b" only, changing from position 1 to position 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
apply(df, 1, plot, type="l")
```

This will loop through all rows, and do a plot.  If you're in an interactive session, they'll probably loop through quite quickly.  If you surround the `apply` with a `file(pdf="lines.pdf")` and `dev.off()` you'll capture all the lines on different pages.